# Multiple file upload in Liferay 6.1

Tags: liferay

Has anyone tried multiple file upload in Liferay 6.1. I was trying to do it the same way as it was in 6.0 and its failing badly. I see begin link on top left of the page and not withing portlet. When i click that and select some files, the control doesnt go to my portlet. I have checked my portlet.xml and verified the portlet-class is proper. Here's the snippet in jsp

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL doAsUserId="<%= user.getUserId() %>" windowState="pop_up" name="uploadFile" var="uploadFileURL" >
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/fileuploadportlet/view.jsp" />
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>


<div class="lfr-dynamic-uploader">
        <div class="lfr-upload-container" id="<portlet:namespace />fileUpload"></div>
    </div>
<div id="<portlet:namespace/>fallback"></div>
<aui:script use="liferay-upload">
    new Liferay.Upload({
        allowedFileTypes: '<%= StringUtil.merge(PrefsPropsUtil.getStringArray(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_EXTENSIONS, StringPool.COMMA)) %>',
        container: '#<portlet:namespace />fileUpload',
        maxFileSize: <%=Long.parseLong(PrefsPropsUtil.getString(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE)) %> / 1024,
        namespace:'<%=renderResponse.getNamespace()%>',
        uploadFile: '<%=uploadFileURL.toString()%>',
        buttonHeight: 100,
        buttonText: 'BEGIN',
        buttonWidth: 100,
        onFileComplete: function(){alert('fileComplete');},
        onUploadError: function(){alert('error');}
    });
</aui:script>
```

And here's the processAction method of my portlet

```
@Override
    public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        System.out.println("Something");
        UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest=PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
        File file =uploadRequest.getFile("file");
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        for(int i=0;i<50000;i++){
            System.out.println("Something");
        }

    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you show us what's happening in developer console ?

Comment: It says tempFileURL is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...empFileURL['method'](tempFileURL['params'], A.bind('_formatTempFiles', instance)...

Comment: Strange error, it's JS engine error. Do you include all engine files?

Comment: Can you show Upload.js file ? And do ypu change it (upload.js) ?

Comment: As far as I know I dont have to include upload.js in my portlet. It's content should be readily available from portal. I didnt change upload.js. You want the upload.js from ROOT?

Comment: Ok if you don't change engine files, don't worry. tempFileURL it's object, not simple variable like string or integer. Do use try use it in other browser Chrome, Safari ?

Comment: Chrome same behavior. In IE the control goes to the Portlet's processAction method, which means its working in IE. But in all the three cases the component appears on top left side as shown in screenshot. Have you tried liferay's multifile upload in 6.1?

Comment: Sorry, no i don't. For my opinion it's a engine error (i.e component no crossbrowser). Sorry for my english, but if it's be my problem, i'll try to find in JS-files tempFileURL object and see what's happening with it. If in JS-files i don't find object/variable tempFileURL that means the component corrupted

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if your `<aui:script>` is correct, below is what is shown in html/portlet/document_library/upload_multiple_file_entries.jsp, I think you are missing the attribute **tempFileURL**:

```
    <aui:script use="liferay-upload">
        new Liferay.Upload(
            {
                allowedFileTypes: '<%= allowedFileExtensions %>',
                container: '#<portlet:namespace />fileUpload',
                deleteFile: '<liferay-portlet:actionURL doAsUserId="<%= user.getUserId() %>"><portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_file_entry" /><portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.DELETE_TEMP %>" /><portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" /></liferay-portlet:actionURL>&ticketKey=<%= ticket.getKey() %><liferay-ui:input-permissions-params modelName="<%= DLFileEntryConstants.getClassName() %>" />',
                fileDescription: '<%= StringUtil.merge(PrefsPropsUtil.getStringArray(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_EXTENSIONS, StringPool.COMMA)) %>',
                maxFileSize: '<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getLong(PropsKeys.DL_FILE_MAX_SIZE) %> B',
                metadataContainer: '#<portlet:namespace />commonFileMetadataContainer',
                metadataExplanationContainer: '#<portlet:namespace />metadataExplanationContainer',
                namespace: '<portlet:namespace />',
                tempFileURL: {
                    method: Liferay.Service.DL.DLApp.getTempFileEntryNames,
                    params: {
                        groupId: <%= scopeGroupId %>,
                        folderId: <%= folderId %>,
                        tempFolderName: 'com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.action.EditFileEntryAction'
                    }
                },
                uploadFile: '<liferay-portlet:actionURL doAsUserId="<%= user.getUserId() %>"><portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/document_library/edit_file_entry" /><portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="<%= Constants.ADD_TEMP %>" /><portlet:param name="folderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(folderId) %>" /></liferay-portlet:actionURL>&ticketKey=<%= ticket.getKey() %><liferay-ui:input-permissions-params modelName="<%= DLFileEntryConstants.getClassName() %>" />'
            }
        );
    </aui:script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the use of tempFileURL and how can I add that from the portlet. From the looks of it, they are trying to call a service method using javascript service api, I dont have such requirement

Comment: tempFileURL is used to get the names of files temporarily stored on a location (defined by tempFolderName) on the server till the time you actually save it as a DLFileEntry i.e. how even when you have not explicitly saved the file, Liferay shows those file the next time you come to the upload page. It returns the names of the files (getTempFileEntryNames) stored (not saved) to show it on the UI so that you can select it through the check-boxes besides the file name and then click on save to save the specific files selected.

Comment: For `Liferay.Service.DL.DLApp.getTempFileEntryNames` to be recognized, do not forget to include service.js like this:
`<script src="/html/js/liferay/service.js" language="JavaScript"> </script>` or declare it in liferay-portlet.xml like this: `<footer-portal-javascript>/html/js/liferay/service.js</footer-portal-javascript>`